# Which video formats works on ipad and Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, ipad, html5-video, mp4, webm

I've embedded webm and mp4 format video on html page using video tag, It's working well on all devices on all browsers except ipad and Mac Pro. What video formats are supported by ipad and Mac Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about the video support of the HTML5 video tag, it depends of your browser and your device (Desktop/Mobile).

See the [table of video support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)